# How to compute the value based on criteria of other cells In Google Sheet Query?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

In Google Sheet Query, how to compute the value based on criteria of other cells?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: what is your criteria?

Comment: I need to add Mary's all pass_A, but not Mary's pass_B. I don't know how to describe it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
=QUERY({A2:D6}, 
"select Col1, Col2, sum(Col3), sum(Col4) where Col1 is not null 
 group by Col1, Col2 
 label sum(Col3) '', sum(Col4) '' ",0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:D; 
 "select A,B,sum(C),max(D) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A,B");
 "offset 1"; 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP is also taking the sum of D like on C instead of it's max.